# Registering native Layer Call in registerNative fails

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have a java file with the following native api signature. ( First.java)

```
public static native int nativePreview(int id, Surface surface);
public static native int nativetest(int id);
```

and in JNI File,

```
static JNINativeMethod methods [] = {
        { "nativetest", "(I)I", (void *)nativetest},

        { "nativePreview", "(IJLandroid/view/Surface;)I", (void *) nativePreview},

},
```

Respective Definitons in JNI File.

```
static jint nativetest(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint myid)
{
  // code..
}


static jint nativePreview(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint myid, jobject surface)
{
    // code 
}
```

For the native Registration i used the below call on

```
env->RegisterNatives(javaConsumerClass, methods, sizeof(methods) / sizeof(methods[0]));
```

**PROBLEM:**

Interestingly, have receive the below error:

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no static or non-static method "Lcom/fd/sample/First;.nativePreview(IJLandroid/view/Surface;)I"

**I have  remove nativePreview() call, the registration is successfully done.**

**Question:**

Have i done in right way of passing surface, or Are there anything that i have overlooked?. please  help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you're saying that your function takes an `int`, a `long`, and an `android.view.Surface`, and returns an `int`:

`(IJLandroid/view/Surface;)I`

But that doesn't match with your definition of `nativePreview`:

```
static jint nativePreview(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz, jint myid, jobject surface)
```

There's no `jlong` in your argument list here.

Comment: Thanks Michael, i figured it out. You are correct. Thanks once again.